# Using LAPACK's DORMQR with non-square Q

Tags: fortran, lapack

I want use LAPACK to calculate Q * x and Q^T * x, where Q comes from the reduced QR factorization of an m by n matrix A (m > n), stored in the form of Householder reflectors and a vector tau, as obtained from DGEQRF and x is a vector of length n in the case of Q * x and length m in the case of Q^T * x.

The [documentation](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/da/dba/group__double_o_t_h_e_rcomputational_ga17b0765a8a0e6547bcf933979b38f0b0.html) of DORMQR states that x is overwritten with the result, which already confuses me, since x and Q * x obviuosly have different dimensions if the original matrix A and subsequently its reduced Q are not square. Furthermore it states that

"Q is of order M if SIDE = 'L' and of order N if SIDE = 'R'."

In my case, only the first half applies and M refers to the length of x. What do they mean by order? I have rarely ever heard the term "order" in the context of non-square matrices, and if so, it would be something like m by n, and not just a single number. Do they mean rank?

Can I even use DORMQR to calculate both Q * x and Q^T * x for a non-square Q, or is it not designed for this? Do I need to pad x with zeros?

Comment: The documentation you link to states that `Q` is a square matrix, no?

Comment: " A is DOUBLE PRECISION array, dimension (LDA,K)
          The i-th column must contain the vector which defines the
          elementary reflector H(i), for i = 1,2,...,k, as returned by
          DGEQRF in the first k columns of its array argument A"

You can call DGEQRF with a non-square A. So I don't think it states explicitly that it has to be square? Correct me if I'm missing something

Comment: "where Q is a real orthogonal matrix".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DORMQR` applies only to Q a square matrix.  Although the input `A` to the procedure relates to elementary reflectors, such as output of `DGEQRF` which can be more general, the documentation has the additional restriction that Q "is a real orthogonal matrix".

Of course, to be orthogonal, Q must be square.

Comment: Right, A doesn't have to be square, but the Householder reflectors are a representation of a square Q (which is never constructed explicitly)